# Why are items apparently duplicated in my mongoDB database when I use find()?

Tags: sql, mongodb, database

I am going through the try.mongodb.org tutorial on their website (embedded terminal emulator on the webpage).  I am on items t4 and t5 (you type tx for items in the tutorial).

In t4 we populate a database.

> ```
> >     t4. Saving and Querying
> >     Try adding some documents to the scores collection:
> >       for(i=0; i<10; i++) { db.scores.save({a: i, exam: 5}) }; 
> >     
> >     Try that, then enter
> >       db.scores.find(); 
> >     to see if the save succeeded. Since the shell only displays 10 results at time,
> >     you'll need to enter the 'it' command to iterate over the rest.
> >     
> >     (enter 'next' when you're ready)
> ```

I made exam 5 + i just for fun:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++) { db.scores.save({a: i, exam: 5+i}) };
```

So what is in the database?  I type in db.scores.find(); and get the following, which is what I had expected, although the order seems random.  Fine.

```
>

[ 
  {   "exam" : 14,   "a" : 9,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d16bcc937439340649c4"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 5,   "a" : 0,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d191cc937439340649c5"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 6,   "a" : 1,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d191cc937439340649c6"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 7,   "a" : 2,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d191cc937439340649c7"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 8,   "a" : 3,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d191cc937439340649c8"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 10,   "a" : 5,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d191cc937439340649c9"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 9,   "a" : 4,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d191cc937439340649ca"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 11,   "a" : 6,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d191cc937439340649cb"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 12,   "a" : 7,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d191cc937439340649cc"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 13,   "a" : 8,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d191cc937439340649cd"   }   }
]
```

In t5 we search for items in that database:

> ```
> >
> 5. Basic Queries You've already tried a few queries, but let's make them more specific. How about finding all documents where a == 2:
> ```
>
> db.scores.find({a: 2});
>
> ```
> Or what about documents where a > 15?   db.scores.find({a: {'$gt': 15}});
> ```

The a== 2 search worked, but the > 15 one did not.  First of all, based on item t4, there should be no entry for a greater than 15.
So I try greater than 6:  `db.scores.find({a: {'$gt': 6}});`

And I get the following output, which is really surprising to me since there should only be 3 entries for a == 7, a == 8, and a == 9.

```
>

[ 
  {   "exam" : 14,   "a" : 9,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d16bcc937439340649c4"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 12,   "a" : 7,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d191cc937439340649cc"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 13,   "a" : 8,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d191cc937439340649cd"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 14,   "a" : 9,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d191cc937439340649ce"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 12,   "a" : 7,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d1a8cc937439340649d6"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 13,   "a" : 8,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d1a8cc937439340649d7"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 14,   "a" : 9,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d1a8cc937439340649d8"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 5,   "a" : 7,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d49fcc937439340649f1"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 5,   "a" : 9,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d49fcc937439340649f3"   }   },
  {   "exam" : 5,   "a" : 8,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d49fcc937439340649f4"   }   }
]
```

If you look at the initially outputted db.scores.find() id's on the right, the last character goes up with each entry -- 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, b, c, d.  But in the duplicated entries, take a look at the entries for a == 9.  We have one ending in 4, one ending in e, and one ending in 3.  It seems like in the brains of the operation the database has 30 entries, not 10.

{   "exam" : 14,   "a" : 9,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d16bcc937439340649c4"   }   },
{   "exam" : 14,   "a" : 9,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d191cc937439340649ce"   }   },
{   "exam" : 5,   "a" : 9,   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "52b1d49fcc937439340649f3"    }   },

I noticed is that if I try to repopulate the database using the loop in t4 it doesn't seem to re-write the values.  i.e. if I use `for(i=0; i<10; i++) { db.scores.save({a: i, exam: 5}) };` as the example had suggested instead of my just for fun `for(i=0; i<10; i++) { db.scores.save({a: i, exam: 5+i}) };`.  Not sure if that is helpful to diagnose the problem but it is another observation.

Comment: If you look at the id's on the right, they go 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, b, c, d.  But in the duplicated entries, take the entries for a == 9.  We have one ending in 4, one ending in e, and one ending in 3.  It seems like in the brains of the operation the database has 30 entries, not 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing something very special,

> I noticed is that if I try to repopulate the database using the loop
>   in t4 it doesn't seem to re-write the values. i.e. if I use for(i=0;
>   i<10; i++) { db.scores.save({a: i, exam: 5}) }; as the example had
>   suggested instead of my just for fun for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
>   db.scores.save({a: i, exam: 5+i}) };. Not sure if that is helpful to
>   diagnose the problem but it is another observation.

Repopulate the database running the query more than once will create 10 rows every single time. db.scores.save doesn't know what document to update because you didn't refer to an _id field, in that case it will always create 10 records. To update existing records you should provide an _id field from the previous inserts. I'm sure you run it more than once and you expect to have always 10 records, what's happening is you're inserting 10 records every time.

Try it removing the collection, run the loop once and execute your find, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you didn't run the commands more than once? What do you see if you run db.scores.find().count(), that will tell you how many items are in the table.

Comment: >
JS Error: TypeError: Property 'count' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: I did run the command to populate the db more than once, but when i use db.scores.find() I only get a list of 10 of them.   But every time I try to repopulate the db I do get 10 more entries when I run the greater than search.  Basically with db.scores.find() I get 10 entries, but with db.scores.find(greater than ... ) I get 10 * n number of times I ran the loop.  So behind the scenes there are entries that db.scores.find() does not show me.

Comment: I may have gotten the count command wrong, but if you read the instructions for the db.scores.find() command above, it states that the console only shows 10 at a time and that you need to type 'it' to show the next 10.